# Jquery function is not getting executed immediately

Tags: jquery, html, reactjs

I have this function in my **react** app (the function is inside `.html` file):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.dropdown-submenu a.dropdown-submenu__templates').on("click", function(e){
            $(this).next('ul').toggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
          });
        });
    </script>
```

The function makes sub-dropdowns appear only on click. The problem with this is when I **log in** first time into my app and click on sub-dropdown it simply closes the parent dropdown (and the sub-dropdown does not appear at all).

I have to **refresh** the page in order the function could get executed.

Why is this happening ? Is there any solution to this ?

inside my **`render()`** function:

```
<li className="dropdown">
    <a
        className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
    >
      <span className="fa fa-files-o"></span>
         Menu&nbsp;
      <span className="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul className="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabIndex="-1" href="#">Item1</a></li>
        <li><a tabIndex="-1" href="#">Item2</a></li>

        <li role="separator" className="divider"></li>
        <li className="dropdown-submenu">
            <a className="dropdown-submenu__templates" tabIndex="-1" type="button">SubDropdown <span className="caret"></span></a>
            <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="#">SubItem1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">SubItem2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Is your `<script>` code position below of your HTML code?

Comment: It's inside `index.html` (inside `<head>` tag); it's not inside the component where `render()` function is

Comment: Can you move the `<script>...</script>` section just before `</body>` tag? (before ending of body tag)?

Comment: @SajibKhan same issue

Comment: this is a very bad use case for adding jquery to react. handle the click and hiding / showing using react its much easier anyways